# Why am I getting this error in a program that tries to count the alphabets of a string?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program:
>   ...Laske aakkoset\Debug\Ohjelmontitehtävä 4.1 Laske aakkoset.exe
>   File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\appcrt\convert\isctype.cpp

`Line: 36 Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255`

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_alpha(const char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (*str) {
        if (isalpha(str[j])) {
            i++;
            j++;
            str++;
        }
        else {
            i = i;
            j++;
            str++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return (0);

}

int main(void) {

    char lol[] = "asdf";
    count_alpha(lol);
}
```

Comment: `i = i;` interesting approach

Comment: C or C++? Choose (Your file has a .cpp extension, but your code is using C practices.)

Comment: Either increment `j` or `str`, not both.

Comment: The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) tells me the behaviour of `isalpha` is undefined unless its input is representable by an **unsigned** char, the assertion condition also suggests that's what is causing the problem. Try a `static_cast<unsigned char>` to be on the safe side ?

Comment: Works perfectly https://ideone.com/1onSl8. Assuming that you want to increment both `str` and `j`

Comment: @imreal that's the joy of undefined behavior - sometimes it works.

Comment: @imreal [Is that so?](https://ideone.com/T7sQye).

Comment: Yea didnt figure I can use isalpha(*str)

Comment: `std::cout << std::count_if(lol, lol + 4, isalpha);`  -- That is basically the entire code if you were really using C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You increment both your char* pointer and the index; but you only need to do one.  It can be edited fairly trivially to:

```
while (str[j]) {
    if (isalpha(str[j]))
        i++;
    ++j;
}
```

or

```
while (*str) {
    if (isalpha(*str))
        i++;
    ++str;
}
```

Attempting to increment both will result in Undefined Behavior for odd lengths as you will start reading memory that hasn't been assigned to your program.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify!  This is a C program that works.  Nothing in the question suggests C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_alpha(const char *str) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*str) {
        if (isalpha(*str)) {
            ++count;
        }
        ++str;
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return count;

}

int main(void) {

    char lol[] = "asdf";
    count_alpha(lol);
}
```

Here is a more C++ ish version.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
int count_alpha(const std::string_view str) {
    int count = 0;
    for(auto c: str) {
        if (isalpha(*str)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    char lol[] = "asdf";
    count_alpha(lol);
}
```

Here's another C++ version that does not use string_view:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
size_t count_alpha(const T &str) {
    size_t count = std::count_if(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::isalpha);
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    char lol[] = "asdf";
    count_alpha(lol);
}
```

Comment: Other than the .cpp extension.

Comment: @michael - Assignment: Rewrite it using std::count_if.

Comment: I try your code and `<string_view>`  doesn't work: `string_view: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's a new thing. C++17 I think. Maybe.

Comment: @michael Look Ma, no string_view.