# Trying to create a bool function that evaluates a char and returns true if char is alphanumeric

Tags: c++

Am I totally off base here? Trying to create a bool function that evaluates char a and returns true if char is alphanumeric.

```
bool isAlphanumeric (char a)
  {
    if (isalnum(a)){
        return true;
    }

    else

return false;

};
```

Comment: And the problem is? You are just adding another unnecessary layer of abstraction.

Comment: Why?  You already have `isalnum` that does the job.

Comment: You don't need `;` at the end

Comment: Amusingly enough, [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627581/why-am-i-getting-this-error-in-a-program-that-tries-to-count-the-alphabets-of-a) just posted a similar question about `isalpha`. Turns out `isalnum` suffers from the [same restriction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) : it's UB unless the argument is EOF or reprensentable by an unsigned char. Maybe your problem is you don't cast the argument to **unsigned** char beforehand and run into an assertion about some argument not being between 0 and 255 ?

Comment: Also, `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can generally be replaced by just `return condition;`

Comment: Thanks guys. I should have probably mentioned that I'm new at this. I'm trying to learn the concept because I'm being asked to do this for a class. Creating a function might not be the most efficient way, but it is what I was asked to do.

Comment: I really doubt that you were asked to add a useless wrapper to an existing library function. At most you were asked to check the ASCII values of the character.

Comment: @Anna but it makes no sense to write a function which does nothing except always calls another function and returns the value of that call. If your teacher wants you to write a function that is already implemented in the standard library, then there is usually an implied rule that you may not use that implementation in your function. Otherwise the exercise has no value.

Comment: I would expect your class would want you to implement the check yourself instead of calling a function from the standard library.

Comment: What's the point of this function in the first place? Why not just call `isalnum` "directly"? Literally all this method does is return the result of the call to that method without adding any other kind of logic, so it seems a little pointless.

Comment: _"Am I totally off base here?"_ I hope so, otherwise that's a useless assignment. @Caninonos No problem was stated, so presumably the intention was to get feedback on the methodology only.

Comment: The instruction is literally: "FILL THIS FUNCTION: evaluates char a, returns true if a is Alphanumeric"

Comment: If I'm misinterpreting, please give me a little guidance. I really want to learn.

Comment: Thank you, by the way. I get what you're saying. I'm just not sure yet how else to handle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to do your homework for you, but I'll help you a little.  Here is one way you could write a function that returns true for when a character is one of these: `c, d, e, f, g, 3, 4, 5, or 6`.

```
bool isSomething(char a)
{
    return a >= 'c' && a <= 'g' || 
           a >= '3' && a <= '6';
}
```

You can expand on that to include all the letters and numbers.  Don't forget to add the uppercase letters, too.

Comment: Thank you so much. So in that case, if it doesn't meet those conditions, bool will return false? Even though it doesn't explicit state "return true"?

Comment: Yes.  The whole expression between `return` and `;` is a bool expression.

Comment: However, C++ standard does not guarantee that all letters be contiguous in the character encoding used by the system, so therefore `a >= 'c' && a <= 'g'` is not guaranteed to behave as you would expect on all systems.

Comment: @user20, it is a safe bet that it will work in the context given.

Comment: @SidS there was no mention of target character encoding, nor target system in the instructions, that were quoted literally. That said, it might be a mistake on behalf of the instructor.

Comment: Agree with @eerorika here, while numeric characters are guaranteed to be contiguous, alphas are not. For example the C++ compilers for the System z boxes use EBCDIC where alphas are in different regions. A safer approach would be to use non-range checks or, better yet, just use the stuff already defined in the `cctype` header.